# How to trigger a ADF pipeline once other triggers are finished

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to Trigger a ADF after completion of 5 other Triggers(each trigger has multiple ADF jobs) finished running successfully
[image: 5 scheduled triggers runs every week]

[image: Each trigger got few pipeline of having each job executing in parallel]

Now i want to schedule or trigger pipeline of jobs which will run after successful completion of all those 5 tirggers. Can some one help me

Comment: You may use try to use REST API provided by Azure - > 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/trigger-runs

You may have to call this using Web Activity and get status and based on trigger run status, you may proceed with operation you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use REST API provided by Azure - >
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/trigger-runs

You may have to call this using Web Activity and get status and based on trigger run status, you may proceed with operation you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The response provided by @ravibhat can be used

Also, you can try below approach

1. Create a File in Storage Account post successful completion of all triggers
2. Set an event based trigger that once the file is available in blob (i.e. completion of past triggers) it will trigger the pipeline
3. This way you can trigger the pipeline based on success of past triggers